# Bounding $f'$ for $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(z)|\le C|z|^{1/2}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function such that $|f(z)-f(w)|\le C|z-w|^{1/2}$ for some $C>0.$ Then show that $|f'(z)|\le C(1-|z|)^{-1/2}.$

I came across this problem from an old exam. I have tried it for two weeks now, but to no avail. By shifting $f,$ we can assume $f(0)=0.$ The most naive thing to do is to just use the definition of $f'(z),$ but this doesn't give anything at all. That is,

\begin{equation}
|f'(z)|=\left|\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}\right|\le \lim_{h\to 0} |h|^{-1/2}.
\end{equation}
Obviously, this is too bad. This doesn't even establish the differentiability. But we already know $f$ is differentiable and using Schwarz lemma, we can get that $$|f'(z)|\le C\frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}.$$
But then I only have an upper on $|f(z)|,$ so the abive inequality does not give anything useful. I tried using the fact $1-|f(z)|^2\le 1+|f(z)|\le 1+|z|^{1/2}.$ This gives $|f'(z)|\le \frac{1}{1-|z|^{1/2}}.$ But the bound is still not good enough.

I also tried using Cauchy's formula for the derivative and use the bound on $f(z)$ to obtain a bound on $|f'(z)|,$ but this yields a very different bound. I don't know what else to try. I have a feeling that somehow Schwarz lemma should be used (may be with Cauchy's formula), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $z \in \Bbb D$ we can apply the Cauchy integral formula for derivatives:
$$
f'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2} \, dw
$$
where $\gamma$ is a circle with center $z$ and radius $r < 1-|z|$. We can assume that $f(z) = 0$, then
$$
 |f'(z)| \le  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\gamma \frac{C|w-z|^{1/2}}{|w-z|^2} \, |dw| = \frac{C}{r^{1/2}} \, .
$$
Taking the limit $r \to 1-|z|$ gives the desired estimate
$$
|f'(z)| \le  \frac{C}{(1-|z|)^{1/2}} \, .
$$

Comment: Aah! Thanks for the answer! I should have seen it! I don’t know why I missed it.